# KineticJS: How do I Crop an Image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I use KineticJs and want to crop an existing image. I tried the following:

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({}); // some kinetic image
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "iPhone",
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000
        });

image.crop({
  x: 0,
  y : 0,
  width : 100,
  height : 100
});

image = image.crop();


layer.add(image);
layer.draw();
stage.add(layer);
```

**The former does not work. How do I crop an existing image with KineticJs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass javascript object with `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties to crop function:

```
image.crop({
  x: 10,
  y : 10,
  width : 66,
  height : 60
});
```

http://jsbin.com/zubek/2/edit

Comment: Why do you do image.width(66).height(60); ?

Comment: Try to comment the line. Cropped image will have same size as original. Looks like scaling. Possibly you don't need it.